# Synaptic Package Manager won't open at all

Tags: synaptic

I've just attempted to open Synaptic Package Manager several times, without success. After I go into the Preferences menu and click on it, my cursor briefly shows that it's waiting or loading, but then it stops and nothing happens. I haven't had this problem with other applications that I can recall. I haven't tried anything besides just clicking on it in the menu; is there anything else I can try or any way I might be able to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Start Synaptic:

```
synaptic-pkexec
```

An *Authentication Required* window for authenticating with your user password will pop up.

If that doesn't work start maybe the authentication-agent is not running. Run the following commands to run the agent and start Synaptic:

```
sudo /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
synaptic-pkexec
```

Comment: After entering the password I get the error "polkit-agent-helper-1: error responce to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie ==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED === Error executing command as another user: Not authorized" and "This incident has been reported."

Comment: The preinstalled command is `synaptic-pkexec`. Maybe Wayland related issue.